# Html video upload sent to a php file using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, html, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

Here's a very simple problem I came across today that's been very frustrating to me:
Say I'm uploading a video file through the HTML 'choose file' input, and I have a submit button that calls an onclick java script function for sending the video to a php file and returns data about the video back to the original page, (something simple like echo $_FILES[$myvideoupload]['name'] ) all through XMLhttpRequest().

Is this possible?

As it is right now, the video simply isn't being passed through my ajax function to the php file. Does document.getElementByID("stuff") work for video files? or is it more about how I should format var in send(var)? Any ideas or knowledge on the subject of passing files through XMLHttpRequest() would be awesome.

Here is my not-so-awesome code with the file attempts commented out in the js. Hope this helps.

```
<html>
<head>

<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function file_upload(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "vidcon.php";

    if(document.getElementById('preset_mp4').checked) {
        pr = document.getElementById("preset_mp4").value;
    }else if(document.getElementById('preset_ogg').checked) {
    pr = document.getElementById("preset_ogg").value;
    }else if(document.getElementById('preset_mov').checked) {
    pr = document.getElementById("preset_mov").value;
    }else if(document.getElementById('preset_wmv').checked) {
    pr = document.getElementById("preset_wmv").value;
    }else if(document.getElementById('preset_3gp').checked) {
        pr = document.getElementById("preset_3gp").value;
}

    //var fd = new FormData();
    //fd.append('uploadedfile', document.getElementByID("uploadedfile").files[0]);
    var vars = "preset="+pr;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = hr.response;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
                }
}

hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="hidden"/>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
Choose pload:<br> <input id="uploadedfile" name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
</form>
Select Output Format for Conversion (changes will be made to conversion settings) <br>
<div class="field form-inline radio">
<input id="preset_mp4" name="preset" type="radio" value="mp4">mp4<br>
<input id="preset_ogg" name="preset" type="radio" value="ogg">ogg<br>
<input id="preset_mov" name="preset" type="radio" value="mov">mov<br>
<input id="preset_wmv" name="preset" type="radio" value="wmv">wmv<br>
<input id="preset_3gp" name="preset" type="radio" value="3gp">3gp<br>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" onClick="javascript:file_upload();"/>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) object to upload a file via ajax. Something like

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('preset', pr);
fd.append('videofile', document.getElementByID("videofileinputid").files[0]);
hr.open("POST", url, true); 
hr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) { 
        var return_data = hr.response; 
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data; 
    } 
} 
hr.send(fd); 
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
```

Note that not all browsers support the FormData object but the are js libraries that simulate an ajax file upload.

Comment: Thank you Musa for the quick response but I am still having trouble understanding that code in the context of my program. What is it that you are appending? Can send() work with both a string and a video file?

Comment: @DrewPaul my mistake, it was suppose to be a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File) object not a input file control and yes you can add strings the link I provided tells you what types of data you can add.

Comment: Sadly, my issue is not resolved. Let me rephrase my question: I have a php file that takes in a video file, along with a string representing presets and returns URLs. I had simple html page that would take a video upload and a radiobutton click for the preset and call on the php file as an action once the submit button was clicked. This would lead you to the page of the php file with the URLs returned. Problem was I want to stay on page and thus I turn to ajax and the confusion ensues. So the fundamental problem I'm having I can't seem to get html user file upload to Ajax to my php file

Comment: I can get the presets to send. But still can't get the upload working. Can this work with file upload?             
    //this is after getting the html data
    var vars = "preset="+pr;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
      var return_data = hr.response;
   document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
     }
    }

    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}

Comment: Thank you musa. I was able to progress beyond this issue because of your knowledge.